# Azure DevOps/VSTS REST API does not get changes of a changeset

Tags: rest, devops, changeset

I'm trying to to get the changes of a changeset but it returns 404. I used this:

```
https://<myname>.visualstudio.com/<projectname>/_apis/tfvc/changesets/291/changes
```

- changeset exists
- without the '/changes' it works, returns the changeset info but **I also need the merge sources**
- tried to specify the API version (e.g.: api-version-5.0)

I created a full control Personal Access Token for the client app but no luck. I tried to use this link in the browser and I got the same result: it works only without '/changes'.

What did I wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is an old Q, this is for anyone else who has same problem, The projectname needs to be removed from the request.
`https://<myname>.visualstudio.com/_apis/tfvc/changesets/291/changes`

You look at the docs and sure enough it's not there but most other REST calls require a project name, so it can be confusing.

Also the docs are not very clear that you can interchange `https://{myName}.visualstudio.com/` for the documented `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}`